# proxy laptop web server through a fixed site

Tags: http, proxy, roaming

I need my customer to be able to evaluate and collaborate on a site that I am developing on my laptop.  However as I roam between my office, home, cafe etc I can't guarantee access with changing IP address, VPNs etc.

Is there a way I can proxy from a fixed server to the laptop?

When the laptop is awake it would establish a connection to the fixed server and of course if I'm offline there will be no service.

Thanks, A

Comment: And the reason you do not set up a dedicated box like most companies do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's services such as http://www.noip.com/ which offer free dynamic DNS to point to your ever-changing connection to which the customer can connect to serving that exact need.